# Vim: why cursor position is not shown in paste mode?

Tags: vim, mode

When I enter `paste` mode in vim, the cursor position (otherwise shown on the modeline) disappears. When I re-enter the `nopaste` mode, it re-appears. What is the reason and intention behind this? Is there a way to have the position shown in the `paste` mode as well?

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured in your /.vimrc file.

Look here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor

I think this option will help it:

```
:set guicursor+=a:blinkon1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `guicursor` setting for this purpose, and set a cursor for your paste mode.

Try: `:help guicursor` in Vim, and you will find the different `mode-list` for this setting, viz.:

```
The mode-list is a dash separated list of these modes:
    n   Normal mode
    v   Visual mode
    ve  Visual mode with 'selection' "exclusive" (same as 'v',
        if not specified)
    o   Operator-pending mode
    i   Insert mode
    r   Replace mode
    c   Command-line Normal (append) mode
    ci  Command-line Insert mode
    cr  Command-line Replace mode
    sm  showmatch in Insert mode
    a   all modes
```

From there, you can clearly see that you need the `a` type mode-list, since it applies to all modes, which includes the paste mode. **One interesting thing to note here is that different cursor type can be set for different modes in Vim :)**

Moreover, the documentation states that:

> The '`a`' mode is different.  It will set the given argument-list for
>     all modes.  It does not reset anything to defaults.  This can be used
>     to do a common setting for all modes.  For example, to switch off
>     blinking: "`a:blinkon0`"

Now, we definitely need the `a` kind of mode. Further down the above list is a list of argument types, and some of the argument types are: `hor` (horizontal bar), `ver` (vertical bar), `block` (block cursor), and so on.

So, having an understanding of the above, we can do:

```
set guicursor+=a:block-Cursor " sets a block cursor for all modes
" Examples of cursor highlighting:
:highlight Cursor gui=reverse guifg=NONE guibg=NONE
:highlight Cursor gui=NONE guifg=bg guibg=fg
```